# How can I perform an ICMP ping in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'd like to have pure network level verification that an IP is reachable, not the HTTP level, since I am trying to verify connectivity with devices that may not implement HTTP.

I already use react-native-udp, react-native-tcp and other native bindings, but does not seem a method to achieve this goal.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have not found a package that does it, I would go with a native solution. There are several packages for iOS, like [GBPing](https://github.com/lmirosevic/GBPing) or [Apple SimplePing](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SimplePing/Introduction/Intro.html) and a quick search in Google showed some pointers on how to implement it for Android. Then you just have to do the binding to JS, for which you can find some help on the [documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-native-ping package to perform ICMP ping on react-native.

To install package:

```
npm i react-native-ping
```